# Inputing pairs into an equation for Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to take two pairs '(a . b) '(c . d) and input them into an equation.

```
(define dist
    (lambda (pr)
(sqrt (+ (expt (- (car pr) (car pr) 2)(expt (- (cdr pr) (cdr pr) 2)))
```

I tried this and a few other ways but I just get errors.

My actual equation seems to work with numbers but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to go about inputting two pairs, or if I'm even supposed to use an equation like the one I have.
 I'm worried I'm thinking about this all wrong and nothing in my book mentions how to deal with two pairs and my teacher won't answer. I'm so confused, any tips or explanations would be wonderful.

EDIT:
I should've mentioned that to test my code I have numbers in place of the letters in the pairs for example:

```
 (dist '(2 . 5) '(3 . 1))
```

I was trying to make it universal since any number has to be able to work with the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Example procedure:

```
(lambda (a b)
  (+ a b))
```

Here `a` and `b` are two arguments. Their names are declared in the formal parameter list and they are used by those names in the body. That `a` and `b` might be numbers can only be seen by how they are used in the body of the procedure, but the formal parameter list itself doesn't say anything about type. They could be pairs and `+` might be lexically bound procedure that does something completely different than adding numbers.

In your procedure you have defined one bound variable `pr`. This seems from the code to be a pair since you are applying both `car` and `cdr` to it. If you need to add another pair you must add it to the formal parameter list with a name of your choosing (like `pr` perhaps was) and use that name in the procedure body.

You can read more about the format of [lambda expressions in the R6RS standard](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-14.html#node_idx_364).

Answer (score 0):

You've shown a function `dist` that accepts two arguments:

```
(dist '(2 . 5) '(3 . 1))
```

where the first argument is `'(2 . 5)` and the second argument is `'(3 . 1)`.  But, your defined a function `dist` that accepts one argument that you've named `pr`.  That won't work - one argument definition but two argument application.

How about:

```
(define dist 
  (lambda (arg1 arg2)
    (let ((x1 (car arg1))
          (y1 (cdr arg1))

          (x2 (car arg2))
          (y2 (cdr arg2)))

      (sqrt (+ (expt (- x2 x1) 2)
               (expt (- y2 y1) 2))))))
```